# Cтранности разных версий WildFly 9 и 26

Tags: wildfly

Мигрирую систему с wildfly 9 на 26 версию, всё ок, работает хорошо, но тут вдруг отваливается на клиенте часть функционала, при проверки обнаружил что date приходит в разных форматах на разных версиях(база одна и та же, обработка на сервере аналогична) и из за этого обработка в условиях падает.

9:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

26:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему это происходит???
И как можно сконфигурировать, что бы было как на девятом?

Так же если важно, бек написан на java и spring framework и поле которое wildfly форматирует является классом java.util.Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге нужно указать в конфигах jackson, что бы он класс Date не превращал в TimeStamp, ибо по дефолту он так и делает и видимо wildfly 9 обрабатывал обратно в строку, но в новых версиях такой фигни нет.

Решение:

В конфиге новый бин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В ApplicationContext.xml если используется не Spring Boot:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)